Error when start MAUI App with multiple projects in one solution
I have been struggling with a problem starting my MAUI app for two days now. The structure of the app should be normal, so I'm surprised that I haven't found anyone else with the same problem.
The app consists of a multiplatform MAUI frontend (.NET8.0 - IOS, Android, Mac), a core library (.NET8.0), a firebase library (.NET8.0) and the respective test projects (.NET8.0). Apparently the app cannot cope with the different target frameworks of the projects, because the error has only occurred since I split the app into different projects to test them better.
The dotnet build is successful, but when I start the app with the following command, I get the following errors:
dotnet build MyMauiApp.sln -t:Run -f net8.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=:v2:udid=16A1C6AA-DC20-4CB6-BB69-AEA5B7D0D47B
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Die Ressourcendatei "/Users/tomfuchs/Repositories/MyMauiApp/MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient/obj/project.assets.json" weist kein Ziel für "net8.0-ios" auf. Stellen Sie sicher, dass die Wiederherstellung ausgeführt wurde, und dass Sie "net8.0-ios" in die TargetFrameworks für Ihr Projekt eingeschlossen haben. [/Users/tomfuchs/Repositories/MyMauiApp/MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient/MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(620,3): error : A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file. [/Users/tomfuchs/Repositories/MyMauiApp/MyMauiApp.Core.Test/MyMauiApp.Core.Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(620,3): error : A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file. [/Users/tomfuchs/Repositories/MyMauiApp/MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient.Test/MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient.Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Die Ressourcendatei "/Users/tomfuchs/Repositories/MyMauiApp/MyMauiApp.Core/obj/project.assets.json" weist kein Ziel für "net8.0-ios" auf. Stellen Sie sicher, dass die Wiederherstellung ausgeführt wurde, und dass Sie "net8.0-ios" in die TargetFrameworks für Ihr Projekt eingeschlossen haben. [/Users/tomfuchs/Repositories/MyMauiApp/MyMauiApp.Core/MyMauiApp.Core.csproj]

Here are the .csproj
MAUI-Project
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

        <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
        The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
        When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
        The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
        either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
        <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

        <OutputType Condition= "'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MyMauiApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MyMauiApp</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.mymauiapp</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient\MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient.csproj">
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
      </ProjectReference>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\MyMauiApp.Core\MyMauiApp.Core.csproj">
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Core-Project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">
      <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Core-Test-Project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">
      <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyMauiApp.Core\MyMauiApp.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


FirebaseClient-Project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">
      <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Resources\Config\apiconfig.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>


FirebaseClient-Test-Project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">
      <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient\MyMauiApp.FirebaseClient.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I have already changed the respective files a bit, for example to prevent the start of side projects in .net8.0-ios. But so far without success.
